# How to test, debug and view console log message of Node js app on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a ubuntu server, on which node js app is running. That app is developed from Sails mvc framework. 
I am asked to fix some server side js code. But the problem is I don't how to test, and debug those code.

First of all, it's linux server without UI, I can't test from browser by localhost, since the program is triggered from HTTP request.

Secondly, it is also unlikely to debug from build-in debugger command line client, for the same reason as the first one. Maybe I just don't know how...

Third, I saw there is some console.log('...') codes, but I don't know where to find the log file.

Hopefully someone could provide some opinions. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the browser - you can do fake requests with `curl`:

```
curl -v -XPOST localhost/path -d 'variable=test'
```

Probbably your app has some logging (logs are saved to a file), so search for it:

- search for the node process PID:

  ```
  ps aux | grep node
  ```

  or

  ```
  ps aux | grep <your application name>
  ```
- view open files of the node process and find your logs

  ```
  ls -l /proc/<node_app_pid>/fd
  ```

Resources:

- [List Open Files for Process](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-list-of-open-files/)

Comment: I found the log. But why it's here? Is it a default directory set by nodeJs Engine or it's OS's feature to catch running programs' log and keep it /proc/<PID>/fd? Can nodejs store the log in other places?

Comment: You could see the `/proc/<node_app_pid>/fd` path as a system feature - it shows files which are open by a process with the given `PID`. All files inside this directory are symlinks (like shortcuts on Windows). You can find the original location each file with this command: `ls -al /proc/<node_app_pid>/fd`.

Comment: Hi, I get another question to ask. I deleted one log file then `ls -al /proc/<PID>/fd` shows that file deleted, even after I created log file, it still shows file is deleted. How can I fix this? Now the log fails to catch nodejs console.log() message.

Comment: Hi, restarting the app should do the trick. If you don't know how to do it pls open a new question and eventually link here.

Answer (score 1):

Sails has it's own built in test suite, using [mocha](http://mochajs.org/).

See the Sails [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Testing) on how to test and debug your application.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS exists outside your browser, as a standalone runtime, so it does not log to your chrome dev console. A node app is started from the terminal using the command `node <filename.js>` or `nodejs <filename.js>`. Since you mentioned sails, maybe you are running it as a `forever` process

To check if you are running it as forever process:

1. Open linux terminal on the server that the app is running on.
2. type `forever list`
3. Find the entry containing the name of your main file
4. Then get the name of the .log file associated with it
5. To see the logs do **`tail -f <log file path>`**